# Google Plus Integration to get Profile posts

Tags: android, google-plus

Is there any API available for getting profile posts in Google Plus for Android App? How can I  post any string using any API in Google Plus? Please let me know if you have any reference...

I have tried with this link below to get the feed
https://plusfeed.appspot.com/1080172850624******** (where "1080172850624********" is the user’s Google profile ID). But when I am going to open this URL in browser, I am getting thsis error below:
"Error: Not Found
The requested URL /1080172850624******** was not found on this server."
Your help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: hint: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

Comment: Me too searching for this... If you get something please do ping me..

Comment: Please do not give profile ID like this in a forum..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google+ SDKs for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/) (or [iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)) to authenticate a user, get an OAuth token, and then you can make [REST API calls to get public data](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) such as posts that the user has made.

For the second question, you cannot write posts to Google+ in any SDK. The user can use the "Share" functions to control what they want share and to whom.